# Com error 0x800401F3 when trying to create Addin in Enterprise Architect EA

Tags: c#, com, enterprise

I'm trying to create an Addin in EA

-Assembly is made visible in COM from Assembly info

-Project is registered for COM Interop

using MS VS C# 2015, .Net 4 and EA 13. but after following all the steps in tutorial below I face this error: Missing (0x800401f3).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o0fm.jpg)

tutorial for Creating EA Addin: 
https://bellekens.com/2011/01/29/tutorial-create-your-first-c-enterprise-architect-addin-in-10-minutes/

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem on my site: Win7 / EA12.1: There was a "0" as value in the registry entry for HK_CURRENT_USER. Deleting that value solved the problem. All add-ins are flagged as being "enabled" now.

Got the information from 
http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37755.msg235804.html#msg235804
reply #6

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My problem was that `COM interop` does not register my dll to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in registry. Try to check the presence of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/projectname.classname` in your registry.

U can examine EA addins by this tool: https://github.com/EXploringEA/EAInstallationInspector
In my case tool shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtM6i.png).